# How to adapt this regex to be agnostic of the order of the key-value pairs

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have constructed this regex to pull the version number of a package from an automatically generated lockfile:

```
\[\[package\]\]\s(?:[a-z-]+ = \"?.*\"?\s)*name = \"NAME\"\s(?:[a-z-]+ = \"?.*\"?\s)*version = \"([ab0-9.]+)\"
```

The subject file looks like this (shortened, there are many such blocks):

```
[[package]]
category = "main"
description = "Some. , - description"
name = "django"
optional = false
python-versions = ">=3.5"
version = "2.2.17"

[package.dependencies]
django = ">=1.8.0"
redis = ">=3"
rq = ">=0.13,<1.0"

[package.extras]
Sentry = ["raven (>=6.1.0)"]
testing = ["mock (>=2.0.0)"]
```

This seems to work well. The problem is that sometimes, the ordering of the two important keys might be different, e.g.:

```
[[package]]
category = "main"
description = "Some. , - description"
version = "2.2.17"
optional = false
name = "django"
python-versions = ">=3.5"
```

Which will cause this regex to fail.

I would like to find a block (starting with `[[package]]` and ending with a newline, that contains the string `^name = \"NAME\"`, and *within that block*, do find the value of the `version` key, regardless of what order they are in.

I have done some reading around lookaheads/lookbehinds, but I could not apply it to this.

Comment: I would use a [regex like this](https://regex101.com/r/aDDG4T/1), if Group 1 is `name` then the Group 2 is the name, else Group 4 is the `name`. This approach needs a bit of coding to post-process the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lookahead assertion to match the name of the package and capture version in main regex:

```sh
\[\[package]]\s(?=(?:[a-z-]+ = "?[^"]*"?\s)*?name = "django"\s)(?:[a-z-]+ = "?[^"]*"?\s)*?version = "([ab0-9.]+)"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/50dL61/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\[\[package]]\s`: Match `[[package]]` followed by a whitespace
- `(?=(?:[a-z-]+ = "?[^"]*"?\s)*?name = "django"\s)`: Positive lookahead to assert that we have a property `name = "django"` somewhere within this package
- `(?:[a-z-]+ = "?[^"]*"?\s)*?`: Match 0 or more property lines
- `version = "([ab0-9.]+)"`: Match `version` property and capture version number in capture group #1